# Lightswitch 2013 app 400 Bad request

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, lightswitch-2013

I deployed a LightSwitch 2013 web application to my local web server using the publishing tool in Visual Studio.  The site works great with no problems.  I am able to load records from the external SQL Server.

When I deploy the same published package to our UAT web server there is an error statement where the data records are displayed that reads "Request failed with status code '400' and status text 'Bad Request'."  I turned on the Failed Request tracing for the application and found 2 logs. Here are the tracing logs:

```
Url -> http://uatwebsrvr:80/LSApp/ApplicationData.svc/$metadata

App Pool -> LSAppPoolv4.0

Authentication -> anonymous

User from token -> NT AUTHORITY\IUSR 

Activity ID -> {00000000-0000-0000-D000-0080000000EE} 

Site -> 1

Process -> 3448

Failure Reason -> STATUS_CODE 

Trigger Status -> 400 

Final Status -> 400 

Time Taken -> 0 msec
```

The second log is identical to this log with the exception of the service being used.

I compared the IIS configs on the UAT server and my Dev server.  The only differences that I could find are some missing assemblies on the UAT server.  But I don't really think this is the issue.  The missing assemblies are these 3:

```
*Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35*
```

The application pools have identical configurations.

One other thing.  I created a very basic Lightswitch application to display some database records to test the database connection.  I deployed this to the UAT web server and this application works perfectly.  This app uses the same database as my real app.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved.  The resolution is to change all the references on the server project to "Copy Local"